# What is the fallacy when someone refuses to be specific

Tags: logic, fallacies, argumentation

A Muslim apologist was debating two Atheists on DW channel in Arabic, the host asked him whether he agrees with "executing atheist apostates".

The Muslim apologist knows that apostates are to be executed, according to his religious belief, but he also knows that answering "yes" would put him at a disadvantage.

So, his answer was something like : "The Atheist should be stopped if he starts preaching atheism".

The host asked him to be specific, what does he mean by "stopped", but the Muslim apologist responded without even mentioning the words "kill" or "execute".. he just used words like : "punish" , "stop", "the atheist is a treat to our society"...etc.

And the host said that he did not answer his question.

At first, I thought this fallacy is a **Red Herring** , but it seems like some kind of appeal to ambiguity.

Is there a name for this fallacy?

**Edit**

A friend suggested *Ignoratio Elenchi*, but I think it can be considered another name for the **Red Herring**, or at least a form of it.

Comment: Wouldn’t this be deviation? Or are you searching for a word seen from the person who deviates, so intentionally not answering the queation with in the back of the mind an agenda or a reason to not get into a discussion while a dialogue is wanted?

Comment: @Ajagar , Thank you , but is there a name for this "fallacy" of deviation? if you ask me how old are you? and I answer : I am still young , what kind of fallacy is that?

Comment: I think maybe Equivocation - *exploiting vagueness in language* to confuse or shift ground.

Comment: Equivocation fallacy is when you use a term that means different things to mean a specific thing : for example - All things are designed, living beings are things therefore living beings are designed... here thing in the first sense does not have the meaning as in the second sense.

Comment: I wanted to opt being evasive but I see you have an answer about that 

Comment: Dissembling.. is another technique which might manifest in this way.

Comment: @Richard , I agree, dissembling, evasion, the name for it I think is "Avoiding the issue Fallacy"

Comment: I dispute that the sequence you described amounts to a flaw at all.  What is the obligation placed on a person being questioned, whether an apologist, a politician, a friend, or any other person?  I think that "fallacy", like all normative statements nowadays, would benefit from a statement of purpose: "fallacy in trying to convince me of ...".

Comment: The host needed to ask specific questions to get specific answers.  There is no fallacy here. Proper follow up questions were not used.  General questions set up the other participant to answer poorly.  This is because you asking general questions turn into AFTER YOU HEAR MY ANSWER then you start changing things such as tone, words, context, etc.  Moral of this is if you have SPECIFIC DETAILS you must be straightforward-- no dancing around the topic. If I KNOW you robbed a bank on Friday 2-8-2019 at 2: 50 pm I should ask questions that include those details. Think you can just lie  right away.

Comment: @elliotsvensson , it was a debate on TV.  When you agree to talk about a certain subject and answer questions (to show that your opponents are wrong), you cannot just dodge questions like that.

Comment: @Logikal , The host is not a sheikh (scholar) to know that apostates are to be executed, he only knows basics about Islam.. Besides, he was always neutral, he asks Atheists, their answers were very specific, and he asks that apologist, his answers were rather ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer will attempt to identify possible fallacies or false fallacies that might be applied to either the Muslim apologist or the atheists although the OP is mainly interested in identifying a fallacy committed by the Muslim.

[Bo Bennett's description of "Weasel Wording"](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/6/Pseudo-Logical-Fallacies) may fit the description of what the Muslim apologist is attempting to do in the argument:

> **Weasel Wording**: Using ambiguous words in order to mislead or conceal a truth: “Save up to 50% or more!” This is more of a marketing gimmick than a fallacy.

However, Bennett also labels this as a "pseudo-logical fallacy", that is, an argumentation pattern that has been identified as fallacious by some, but is not fallacious according to Bennett's three criteria:

> 1. **It must be an error in reasoning**, not a factual error.
> 2. **It must be commonly applied to an argument** either in the form of the argument or the interpretation of the argument.
> 3. **It must be deceptive** in that it often fools the average adult.

Bennett also describes a pseudo-logical fallacy that might apply to the atheists countering the Muslim apologist:

> **Argument by Rhetorical Question**: Setting up questions in such a way to get the answers you want. This is a name for an argumentation strategy covered by both the loaded question and leading question fallacies.

This illustrates that both sides in this argument could accuse the other of being fallacious if the context is appropriate.

Simply questioning whether the other side has committed a logical fallacy may be an example of the [Complex Question Fallacy](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/69/Complex-Question-Fallacy), which Bennet considers to be a legitimate fallacy:

> A question that has a presupposition built in, which implies something but protects the one asking the question from accusations of false claims.  It is a form of misleading discourse, and it is a fallacy when the audience does not detect the assumed information implicit in the question and accepts it as a fact.

Bennett gives the following illustrations of these kinds of these questions with built-in presuppositions:

> - How many times per day do you beat your wife?
> - How many school shootings should we tolerate before we change the gun laws?

Just asking questions such as these may involve deception by prejudicing the audience against the opposing side.

Contrast these with questions seeking factual information which would not be logically fallacious, such as, "How long can one survive without water?"

One should be careful when questioning and perhaps accept whatever the opponent offers as an answer. Later questioning might make evident a contradiction with an earlier answer.

---

Bennett, B. "Complex Question Fallacy" Logically Fallacious https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/69/Complex-Question-Fallacy

Bennett, B. "Pseudo-Logical Fallacies" Logically Fallacious https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/6/Pseudo-Logical-Fallacies

Comment: Thank you so much Frank, so both sides committed these (pseudo?)-fallacies.  the Muslim apologist already said in a post on Facebook that "a bullet in the head of an atheist is more useful than a thousand debate".  So, the host and the atheists know his point already.  Best +1

Comment: I am not sure the host committed a "Complex Question Fallacy", the host's question was quite straightforward, and he gave him more than 10 min to answer : "Do you agree or disagree with executing apostates". The question was from the host, and he is talking about execution, and not prison or fine.

Comment: @SmootQ He may not have and such questions perhaps need to be asked to clarify  what one side is advocating. What I find interesting about the complex question fallacy is the "built-in presuppositions" that such questions bring with them. Just asking such a question can be damaging. But maybe it needs to be asked.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting the fact that not everything is a "fallacy"!

Comment: @ChrisSunami nevertheless avoiding a question seems just wrong

Comment: @SmootQ  It may be.  But "wrong" is NOT the same as fallacious.  Fallacy is a technical term meaning an illegitimate argument.  No argument means no fallacy.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about **Evasion**, which is an act that deceives by stating a true statement that is irrelevant or leads to a false conclusion.

Now we may wonder: is avoiding the question a logical fallacy ?

Well, yes, it is an informal fallacy of presenting an argument that may or may not be logically valid, but whose result fails to address the question.

The Latin name for this fallacy is **ignoratio elenchi**.

Comment: But, Ignoratio Elenchi is the latin name for the Red Herring fallacy.. or maybe there is another name for this one? - Thank you. +1

Comment: In *ignoratio elenchi* you can completely change the subject and refuse answering the question, but the fallacy I am asking about is not that, it is just not being , or refusing to be, specific while answering the question

Comment: For example : if you ask me how old are you? and I answer : I am still young , what kind of fallacy is that? That is not an *ignoratio elenchi*.

Comment: It's still evasion and still based on counting on the fact that the result is not logically valid or accurate enough. So yes, the 2 (IE and RH) are similar forms of the same thing.

Comment: yes it is evasion, but what is the name of the fallacy ? I think evasion looks like "Avoiding the issue" https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/61/Avoiding-the-Issue

Comment: All examples related here are forms of evasion, no matter how you name them.